# Проблема с внешним CSS файлом

Tags: css

При подключении стилей во внешнем CSS файле они игнорируются некоторыми браузерами (firefox, IE), а если написать эти же стили в свойствах тега через атрибут style всё работает нормально. Подскажите в чем может быть причина?

Comment: можно пример кода с реального сервера или онлайн пример

Answer (score 1):

Возможна ошибка в стилях, либо есть стили с более высоким приоритетом.
Проверьте, какие стили уже есть у элемента через FireBug.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Стиль простой наврятли дело в ошибках, а на счёт приоритета, дописывал important для свойства не помогло. Сейчас полностью перебираю дизайн. Самое интересное, что в Гугл хроме всё работает а в мозиле и IE нет.

Comment: А у элемента точно есть этот стиль в FF?

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов как всегда, несколько: либо у вас файл не подключается, либо в нем неправильно прописаны элементы, либо стили перекрываются, либо, в случае картинок, вписан путь относительно документа, а не css файла. В любом случае, подебажьте проблемные элементы через firebug.

Answer (score 0):

а пробовали подключить в виде @import url(путь к файлу); ?

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Обязательно попробую, просто никогда не пользовался таким подключением файлов..)